# Precompiling a validator function in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I am writing a custom validator package. One of the requirements is to be able to provide a function to run on the control value (for example check two passwords match). I want to be able to do something like:

```
<input data-validator-func="validFn" .../>
```

And whenever the input is changed call this function with the text of the input as a parameter. I want to make this run as fast as possible, so to cache it I wanted to do:

```
fn = eval("function(val) { " + $(elem).attr('data-validator-func') + "(val);}");
```

The idea being to precompile a function call and then simply do:

```
valid = fn($(elem).val());
```

However, when I try this firefox throws an exception on the initial eval "SyntaxError: function statement requires a name".

I'm not sure what is going wrong here. Can anyone help?

Comment: eval("function validFn(val) { " + $(elem).attr('data-validator-func') + "(val);}");

Comment: But I want an anonymous function here, not a named function.

Comment: Well then you have to declare it such as validFn = function(){} then do eval(validFn(val));

Comment: I can't believe people are still using eval...

Comment: Design consideration though: If you're writing a form that includes, say "your phone number", "emergency phone number", "cell phone number", "bank phone number", do you really want your HTML writers to have to paste the same JavaScript function into each of those? This solution doesn't strike me as reusable (and actually might cause a security hole)

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe "function statement requires a name". As long as you're going to engage in this hackery, why not use the `Function` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping it in parens makes it work

```
eval("( function(){} )");
```

To address your code in particular

```
fn = eval("(function(val) { " + $(elem).attr('data-validator-func') + "(val);})");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var code = $(elem).attr('data-validator-func');
var fn = new Function('val', code).bind(elem);
```

This is a bit less dodgy than `eval`, because it can't bind anything to your local variables and just because it involves less string fiddling. In addition, the `bind` means that the user can use `this` in the function and it will refer to the element.

Of course, a better way is probably not putting JavaScript in an HTML attribute, but I don't know the whole story here.